# Neo4j java rest binding

Tags: java, rest, neo4j

I am trying to get more familiar with the java-rest-binding (https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding).

My main question is what operations of the GraphDatabaseService supports.

For example I read here that `GlobalGraphOperation` are not supported, but the tests use them. I have the final release (2.0.1). In adittion to this I would like to know if there is a significant defference between

```
GraphDatabaseService gds = new RestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
```

and

```
RestAPI restAPI = new RestAPIFacade("http://localhost:7474/db/data");`
```

or it's the same way to connect to the neo4j server.

Answer (score 1):

The java-rest-binding is a flaky abstraction over REST-Operations over the wire. Unless you have a really good reason to use it, I wouldn't use it.

What's your actual use-case that you want to solve?

Comment: What would you suggest to use with Scala 2.11 (not 2.10) ?